# jQuery Mobile: Controlling what gets added to URL bar

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile site using jquery mobile. It will contain a few static internal pages for settings etc., but primarily will be loading/linking external pages.

I have two requirements.

- I do not want internal pages to affect the URL bar or add to the
  urlHistory (as hashes, ie index.html/#settings)
- when the user loads a new external page, I do want it to show in the
  URL bar and add to the urlHistory.

This sounds simple enough, but I can not seem to get it working.

I tried the following in mobileinit. This simply NEVER modified the URL, for internal and external links.

```
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery mobile to load mostly external pages, kind of makes it useless as you are only really using the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, mobilinit is a tricky event, it must be triggered before jQuery Mobile is loaded, here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        });
    </script>       
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="operations.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="test-listview">
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=1">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=2">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=3">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=4">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=5">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Test it, you will find it satisfies your every requirement.

Comment: Appreciate your response and apologize for not posting code. I do in fact run my mobileinit before I call Jqmobile. And I can confirm that it is being processed... but the changeHash code allows ZERO change in URL (the url never changes from the original url).

Answer (score 0):

OK,
After testing various things I ran across a possibly solution that does not involve mobileinit.
For all links that I do NOT want reflected in the url bar, I set programmatically:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#home", {changeHash: false, transition:'fade'});
```

The key here is the changeHash set to false. This will transition to the page 'home' but will not make any changes in the URL bar.

I am unsure if I can do the same thing within an href tag.